# (0, _reactNavigation.withOrientation) is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I 'm working with a React native app and tried to add a new component from other project.
I'm facing this issue, anybody got an idea?
[image]

package.json

> "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.9"

render function on main component

```
render() {
    return (
      <StyleProvider
        style={getTheme(
          this.props.themeState === "material" ? material : undefined
        )}
      >
        <Drawer
          ref={ref => {
            this._drawer = ref;
          }}
          open={this.props.drawerState === "opened"}
          type="overlay"
          tweenDuration={150}
          content={<SideBar />}
          tapToClose
          acceptPan={false}
          onClose={() => this.props.closeDrawer()}
          openDrawerOffset={0.3}
          panCloseMask={0.2}
          styles={{
            drawer: {
              shadowColor: "#000000",
              shadowOpacity: 0.8,
              shadowRadius: 3
            }
          }}
          tweenHandler={ratio => {
            return {
              drawer: { shadowRadius: ratio < 0.2 ? ratio * 5 * 5 : 5 },
              main: {
                opacity: (2 - ratio) / 2
              }
            };
          }}
          negotiatePan
        >
          <MyRouter />
        </Drawer>
      </StyleProvider>
    );
  }
```

Comment: which version of react navigation do you have installed? could you please share the code too?

Comment: Thanks, @HelmerBarcos. I added some information.

Comment: the error is associated with the method withOrientation from react-navigation. but in the code you shared, i dont see any line of code that refers to it.

Comment: I didn't use such functions in react-navigation, and not enough documentation with it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved it by using yarn instead of npm.

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/3216#issuecomment-418680074